# Centos 7 server traffic blocker

Tags: web-server, centos7, traffic

Sometimes my website is lot of traffic and looks it is very slow. Log details can see someone ip address do lot of traffic to server. I need reboot my server so speed come back to normally.

It is available free someone automatic "ip address" blocker for Centos 7 if someone "ip address" do lot of traffic to server?

Comment: Put HAProxy in front of it.

Comment: This good with cloudlinux if possible? I don't have experience HAProxy + My magento 2 website.

Comment: HAProxy should be available in the repo.